# Joining two tables (from different databases) based on whether lat and long from one table are present in the polygon of the other

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x, mariadb

I'm trying to join two tables (in different databases: database_1 and database_2) based on whether the latitude and longitude (stored in one table) falls inside the defined polygons of the other table. Just for some context, my first table (containing lat and long in database_1) looks like:

```
          Code  price  Latitude  Longitude  
0         A001   1200     43.65      -79.1
1        A3421    150     40.78      -73.9
2            B    300     42.82      -67.3
3          HCO    450     22.22      -22.2
4         WREA    200     39.80       32.3
```

And the other table (containing the polygon of type geometry defined by the column geometry) stored in database_2:

```
          tier_name  tier2_name              geometry  
0          Sample 1    Sample 1  [GEOMETRY - 2.7 KiB] 
1          Sample 2    Sample 2  [GEOMETRY - 2.7 KiB]
2          Sample 3    Sample 3  [GEOMETRY - 2.7 KiB]
3          Sample 4    Sample 4  [GEOMETRY - 2.7 KiB]
4          Sample 5    Sample 5  [GEOMETRY - 2.7 KiB]
...             ...         ...                   ...
```

I would ideally want my result to contain the appropriate tier_name and tier_name2 along with all the fields of the first table:

```
          Code  price  Latitude  Longitude  tier_name  tier2_name  
0         A001   1200     43.65      -79.1   Sample 5    Sample 5  <-- The point (43.65 and -79.1) is in the polygon sample 5
1        A3421    150     40.78      -73.9   Sample 5    Sample 5
2            B    300     42.82      -67.3                         <-- This point is in none of the polygons of dataframe #2 
3          HCO    450     22.22      -22.2   Sample 2    Sample 2
4         WREA    200     39.80       32.3   Sample 3    Sample 3
...        ...    ...       ...        ...        ...        ....
```

---

My attempt at the solution (since I'm using python) was to do a join based on whether st_within as follows:

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='', unix_socket='/data/mysql/mysql.sock', database='database_2')

test=pd.read_sql("""SELECT tier_name, tier2_name, st_astext(geometry),  
                    FROM `table_2`
                    JOIN `database_1`.`table_1` as Table1
                    ON ST_WITHIN(Point([Table1.Latitude, 
                    Table1.Longitude], 4326), `table_2`.geometry)
                    """, cnx)
```

However, the error I keep getting is:

```
1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '[database_1].[Table_1] Table_1
                    ON ST_WITHIN(geometry::P' at line 5
```

Comment: If "different databases" are different databases within the same MySQL server instance then simply specify database name for **each** table name - even when the table is a table from current database. *My attempt at the solution* It is synthactically wrong for MySQL because you use square brackets for the object names quoting (`[database_1].[Table_1]`) which is specific for MS SQL (SQL Server). Also you use `geometry::Point` which is not legal for MySQL too... Look for your DBMS name and version one more time (provide complete output for `SELECT VERSION();` query).

Comment: @Akina, thanks for the input, I forgot to update my query. My version is 10.1.48-MariaDB.

Comment: MySQL and MariaDB do not use brackets anywhere in the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For MariaDB you should be using backticks to quote identifiers (not necessary). This query should work assuming the databases are both on the same MariaDB instance

```
SELECT
    `t1`.`Code`,
    `t1`.`price`,
    `t1`.`Latitude`,
    `t1`.`Longitude`,
    `t2`.`tier_name`,
    `t2`.`tier2_name`
FROM `database_2`.`table_2` t2
JOIN `database_1`.`Table_1` t1
    ON ST_WITHIN(Point(`t1`.`Latitude`, `t1`.`Longitude`), `t2`.`geometry`)
```

Comment: thanks, this worked like a charm!